# Can I ionise an atom purely optically?

Tags: atomic-physics

Can I remove the outermost electron of an atom just by shining an EM wave? Or will this just go in a crazy high excited state that is so weakly bound it will be removed by any kick / external potential difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intensity is high enough, optical radiation will certainly ionize atoms via multi-photon ionization.

Comment: Wavelength also matters. It must be short enough to excite the electron from ground to the first excited state.

Comment: Actually, his point is that multiphoton ionization gets around that...